# Is there a way to format the equation like this?

Tags: equations

My friend is taking pre-calculus class, and I would like to create some notes for him. Is there a way I can do the following in latex?

Right now I only have the very basic down. I want to make it look nicer and more personal. (The color can stay black, but I used a red pen to show what I wanted to do. Thank you all in advance.)

[image]

```
$ax^2 \ + \ bx \ + \ c \ \ \ \ (where \ a \neq 1)$\\
$k_1 \ + \ k_2 \ = \ b \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ \ (k_1)(k_2) \ = \ ac$ \\ \\ 
$ax^2 \ + \ bx \ + \ c \ \ \ \ (where \ a \ = \  1)$\\
$k_1 \ + \ k_2 \ = \ a \ \ \ \ and \ \ \ \ (k_1)(k_2) \ = \ b$
```

Comment: So you want to underline and right-brace the equation set. What about the horizontal alignment?

Comment: @Werner In the middle would be great, I am having most difficult with the right-brace and add the word to remind him they are different.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Example with coloring:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand*{\colorunderline}[2]{%
  \underline{#2\color{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\[
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \left.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace
  \begin{array}{l@{\qquad}l}
    ax^2 + bx + c & (\colorunderline{red}{\text{where}\quad a \ne 1})\\
    k_1 + k_2 = b & \text{and}\qquad (k_1)(k_2) = ac\\[2ex]
    ax^2 + bx + c & (\colorunderline{red}{\text{where}\quad a = 1})\\
    k_1 + k_2 = a & \text{and}\qquad (k_1)(k_2) =b
  \end{array}
  \color{red}
  \right\}
  \textcolor{red}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
      very\\
      different!
    \end{tabular}%
  }
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

The same distance of the red underline can be achieved, if the second case includes `\vphantom{\ne}`:

```
(\colorunderline{red}{\text{where}\quad a = 1\vphantom{\ne}})
```

> [image: Result]

### Colored \underline

The "simple" definition

```
\newcommand*{\colorunderlinex}[2]{%
  \underline{#2\color{#1}}%
}
```

works with a trick. First TeX processes the argument to make a math formula. `\color` automatically uses `\aftergroup` to reset the color. Then the math formula is put in a vertical box. The latest whatsit in the formula is the switch to the underline color. Then TeX puts the line below the formula. Finally the color whatsit that was set by `\aftergroup` resets the color after the underlined box construct.

However this is not compatible to coloring package `luacolor` via LuaTeX attributes. The following definition works for package `luacolor`. It needs package `xcolor`, because this package adds a concept of a current color (`.`).

The current color `.` is saved with name `current`. Then the color for the underline is set for the whole construct. The math formula is set with the previously saved color `current`:

```
\newcommand*{\colorunderline}{}
\def\colorunderline#1#{%
  \colorunderlineAux{#1}%
}
\def\colorunderlineAux#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
    \colorlet{current}{.}%
    \color#1{#2}%
    \underline{%
      \begingroup
        \color{current}#3%
      \endgroup
    }%
  \endgroup
}
```

- This definition also supports an optional argument with the color model the same way, `\textcolor` implements it.
- The additional grouping level inside `\underline` is necessary, if the color is implemented via whatsits (package `color`). In the latter case the "simple" definition is more efficient, because it only uses two color whatsits instead of four in the definition for `luacolor`.

Comment: out of interest, how do you set that nice background colour?

Comment: @Thruston: Transparent background of the image in a quotation block (`>`).

Comment: Neat. But going back to the answer, do you think it would look better if you included the parentheses in the underlining?  Then both rules would be the same distance from the baseline.

Comment: @Thruston: I was closely following the image in the question. You can also get the same distance, if `\vphantom{\ne}` is added to the second case, see the updated answer.

Answer (score 22):

I wouldn't use underlining to emphasize material -- better to just typeset the material in red.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,xcolor}
\newcommand{\redemph}[1]{\text{\color{red}#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{drcases*}
ax^2+ bx+c    &\redemph{where $ a \neq 1$}\\
k_1 + k_2 = b &\text{and $k_1k_2 = ac$} \\[2ex]
ax^2 + bx + c &\redemph{where $a =  1$}\\
k_1 + k_2 = a &\text{and $k_1k_2 = b$}\\
\end{drcases*} \redemph{\bfseries Very Different!}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I agree, but I would additionally define a `\newcommand{\mathemph}[1]{\color{red}#1}` inside that environment to keep markup semantic

Comment: @WChargin - Thanks for this suggestion, which I've incorporated in the MWE as a macro named `\redemph`.

Answer (score 20):

[`mathtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides `rcases`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]
\[
  \begin{rcases}
    ax^2 + bx + c \quad \text{\underline{(where $a \neq 1$)}} \\
    k_1 + k_2 = b \quad \text{and} \quad k_1 k_2 = ac \\ \\
    ax^2 + bx + c \quad \text{\underline{(where $a = 1$)}} \\
    k_1 + k_2 = a \quad \text{and} \quad k_1 k_2 = b
  \end{rcases}
  \begin{tabular}{l} VERY \\ DIFFERENT \end{tabular}
\]
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use an `array`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[ 
    \left. 
   \begin{array}{l@{\qquad}l}
    ax^{2} + bx + c  &  \text{\underline{(where $a\neq 1$)}} \\
    k_{1} + k_{2} =b &  \text{and $(k_{1})(k_{2}) = c$}\\[2\jot]
    ax^{2} + bx + c  &  \text{(where $a\neq 1$)} \\
    k_{1} + k_{2} =b &  \text{and $(k_{1})(k_{2}) = c$}
  \end{array}
  \right\} \text{Very different}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

With stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\culine[2]{\textcolor{#1}{\protect\underline{\textcolor{black}{#2}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
  \setstacktabulargap{2em}\setstackgap{L}{1.2\baselineskip}
  \left.\tabularCenterstack{ll}{
    $ax^2 + bx + c$ & (\culine{red}{where$\quad a \ne 1$})\\
    $k_1 + k_2 = b$ & and $\quad(k_1)(k_2) = ac$\\\\
    $ax^2 + bx + c$ & (\culine{red}{where$\quad a = 1$})\\
    $k_1 + k_2 = a$ & and$\qquad (k_1)(k_2) =b$
  }
  \color{red}\right\}\textsf{\small\textcolor{red}{\Centerstack[l]{VERY\\DIFFERENT!}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With Plain TeX `vcenter` and `halign` and a custom "underline-in-red" macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\def\ur#1{\setbox0\hbox{#1}\hbox to 0pt{\color{red}\vrule depth 3.2pt height -2.6pt width \wd0\hss}\box0}
$$
\left.
\vcenter{\openup3pt\halign{$#$\hfil\quad\cr
  ax^2+bx+c \quad (\ur{where $a\not=1$})\cr
  k_1+k_2=b \quad\hbox{and}\quad (k_1)(k_2) = ac\cr
  \noalign{\bigskip}
  ax^2+bx+c \quad (\ur{where $a=1$})\cr
  k_1+k_2=a \quad\hbox{and}\quad (k_1)(k_2) = b\cr
  }}
\color{red}\right\} 
\hbox{\color{red}Very different!}
$$
\end{document}
```

[image]